# Replace the text 'Chapter' with custom text in Memoir

Tags: memoir, chapters, naming

How can I replace the word 'Chapter' with some other text string in Memoir class?

So, instead of Chapter 1, it appears as, say, MyChapter 1.

Also, the text is in Devanagari script so MyChapter will be some Devanagari text string.

Comment: \renewcommand{\chaptername}{MyChapter}, but I can not say anything about Devanagari script.

Comment: @ChristianH. worked perfectly --- even with Devanagari. Thanks!

Also, if you make it an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree that this is a duplicate. OP specifically requests a solution for `memoir`, while the cited question deals with `article`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{MyChapter}
```

at any position before you the first chapter which should get another chapter name.

If you want to rename all chapter names, put the command in the preamble.

Comment: Think you have set the record for the fastest answer :)
Thanks!!

Comment: @deshmukh: Perhaps, but is more important that it works for your needs